# MySQL Workbench - Define database in connection settings

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I was wondering whether there is a way to define a specific database in the connection setup of MySQL Workbench (I know this works with other database software). Sometimes I have a lot of different databases on one server and I only want to access one with one connection. Can I specify the database in the connection settings somehow?

Comment: `Default Schema` option :)

Answer (score 3):

YES, On the home tab Click the `+` in `MySQL Connections`. And put the database name in the `Default Schema:` when you fill in all the usual info about ip address etc

Now if you only want to see the one database, then create a new MySQL user account and only allow this new account access to this single database. Then change the connection to the database to use the newly created MySQL account.

I guess you are seeing all the databases because you are using the `root` account.

Comment: Ahh, that's what this if for! I entered the name and when I connected, it pre-selected my database. But other databases were still displayed. Is there also a way to restrict the connection to only this single database?

Comment: Yes, give me a few seconds to add to answer